# How can I split a file into a given number of parts in Perl? (On Unix)

Tags: linux, perl, bash, sed, awk

I have several large files, each of which I want to chunk/split it in to 
predefined number of parts.

Is there an efficient way to do it in Unix (e.g. via awk/sed/perl)?

Also each file can have varied number of lines.

```
File1.txt 20,300,055 lines
File2.txt 10,033,221 lines
etc...
```

Comment: Do you want to split them into predefined size files (ie, 1MB), or do you want to split it into `n` number of parts, and if this latter, do you want to split it by number of lines, or into equal sized files?

Comment: Why was the title changed to be about Perl when the question isn't about Perl?

Comment: Whatever you think about either wording, Perl is mentioned in both, so it's not really a change.

Comment: Either Perl or Unix is changed to just Perl and it's not really a change?

Comment: @Kinopiko I am not sure what you think Perl/Unix means, but I took it to mean Perl on Unix. The OP could have rolled back the change if he did not agree with it.

Comment: The question says "Is there an efficient way to do it in Unix (e.g. via awk/sed/perl)?". It doesn't specify Perl.

Comment: As you've surely noticed, that aspect of the question has *not* been modified by Sinan's edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to split each file into files of a fixed number of lines or bytes, you can use the [`split`](http://ss64.com/bash/split.html) command.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=90768). You may need to find the number of parts to be splited it too first.

Answer (score 2):

you can use csplit, which can split by context. Check the man/info page of csplit for more info.